# Busca em Array com Objeto e Like no Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, algoritmo-de-busca, objetos

Estou tentando buscar o valor de uma key dentro de um objeto dentro de um array, consigo trazer todos os valores da detyerminada key, o que não consegui por não entender direito o funcionamento foi trazer apenas o valor de um objeto caso um outro objeto esteja com o valor que desejo, tipo um like no mysql

Este é meu Array com Objetos

```
let meuArray = [
  { index: 1, bestOffer: true, title: plan[1].friendly },
  { index: 2, bestOffer: false, title: plan[2].friendly }
]
```

E eu busco desta forma

```
this.meuArray.map(o => o.title)
```

Isso me traz todos os title separados por uma virgula `,`
Tentei fazer assim

```
this.meuArray.map(o => o.bestOffer && o.title)
```

e ele me trouxe apenas o que eu desejo, que é title do bestoffer `true` porém exibiu `false` separado por virgula `,` junto com o title em questão
como eu procedo para obter apenas o title onde o bestoffer está true utilizando este exemplo `this.meuArray.map(o => o.title)` como se fosse um like no mysql? tentei `in`, `indexof`, `has` entre outros

Comment: O que você quer fazer é **filtrar** um objeto, não **mapear** o mesmo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá, acredito que você esteja procurando pela função **filter**. A utilização dela é bem simples, e pode ser encadeada para fazer o mapeamento como no seu próprio exemplo. Ficaria algo semelhante à isso:

```
this.meuArray
    .filter(o => o.bestOffer)
    .map(o => o.title)
```

Comment: funcionou lindamente, eu só não soube utilizar, então são dois blocos, primeiro filter depois map, muito obrigado, isso que eu não estava entendendo

Comment: Exatamente Roberto! Depois dê uma olhadinha nessa documentação do filter:

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro

Com certeza vale apena a leitura.

Comment: Muito obrigado Murillo de Morais