# Busca em Array com Objeto e Like no Javascript para retornar o Index achado

Tags: javascript, array, algoritmo-de-busca, objetos

Recentemente fiz esta pergunta [Busca em Array com Objeto e Like no Javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/396464/busca-em-array-com-objeto-e-like-no-javascript) e me foi respondida da melhor maneira possível, estou estudando a documentação porém com algumas dificuldades onde me deparei com esta no caso, eu posso obter o valor que desejo utilizando o filter e o map de acordo com a resposta da pergunta, mas aí surgiu uma outra dificuldade, e para eu trazer o indice em que ele foi achado? eu só obtenho 0 pois só foi localizado 1 item, logo o indice sempre será 0 se eu utilizar este trecho

```
this.array.filter(o => o.bestOffer).map(function (o, i) { return i }))
```

ou seja, ele achou o que procuro mas só existe 1 então o retorno será 0, mas no caso o array contem 4 itens e este cujo procuro está na posição 1 ou seja é o segundo da lista, como obter o número 1 pois é lá que ele está?

```
  array: [
    { bestOffer: false, title: planosControle[0].friendly },
    { bestOffer: true,  title: planosControle[1].friendly },
    { bestOffer: false, title: planosControle[1].friendly },
    { bestOffer: false, title: planosControle[2].friendly }
  ],
```

no momento, achei o indexOf e utilizei esta forma `this.array.findIndex(o => o.bestOffer)` e parece ter funcionado

Comment: no momento, achei o indexOf e utilizei esta forma this.array.findIndex(o => o.bestOffer) e parece ter funcionado

Comment: O indexOf() vai retornar apenas o index do primeiro elemento que atender o critério da callback. Caso sempre tenha apenas 1 elemento que você busque, problema nenhum de usar. Porém se não for esse o caso, terá problema. O retorno sempre igual a 0 que você está tendo é por causa que seu map() está sendo feito em um novo array retornado pelo filter(), que é apenas o array com o elemento que você está procurando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O retorno sempre igual a 0 que você está tendo é por causa que seu `map()` está sendo feito em um novo array retornado pelo `filter()`, que é apenas um array contendo os elementos que atenderam o critério da callback, no caso do exemplo apenas um elemento.

O `indexOf()` vai retornar apenas o index do primeiro elemento que atender o critério da callback. Caso **sempre tenha apenas 1** elemento que você busque, problema nenhum de usar. Porém se não for esse o caso e você quiser achar o index de um ou mais elementos de um mesmo array, terá problema.

Uma solução seria implementar uma nova função no prototype do Array, inspirada no `findIndex()` que já existe, como o código abaixo:

```
Array.prototype.findAllIndex = function(predicate) {
    if (this === null) {
      throw new TypeError('Array.prototype.findIndex called on null or undefined');
    }
    if (typeof predicate !== 'function') {
      throw new TypeError('predicate must be a function');
    }
    var list = Object(this);
    var length = list.length >>> 0;
    var thisArg = arguments[1];
    var value;
    var indexs = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      value = list[i];
      if (predicate.call(thisArg, value, i, list)) {
        indexs.push(i);
      }
    }
    return indexs.length > 0 ? indexs : -1;
  };
```

Essa nova função do array vai retornar um array de todos os index dos elementos compatíveis com seu critério na callback ou `retorna -1` caso não encontre nenhum elemento compatível.

Você pode chamar essa nova função da seguinte maneira:

```
this.array.findAllIndex(o => o.bestOffer);
```

O `findIndex()` também só retorna o index do primeiro elemento compatível com o critério da callback, não sendo viável para seu uso caso você queira retornar o index de mais de um elemento no array.

Espero que tenha ficado claro e isso te ajude.

Comment: muito bom, realmente só percebi o novo array depis, ao ler mais vezes reparei que o map cria um novo array por isso trazia só 0 pois só tinha 1 elemento como explicou, de fato o indexof deu certo por que sómente 1 elemento recebera a flag, como sitou, se 2 elementos receberem a flag ai teria que evoluir a função, muito obtigado